# firestore cloud function - needs minutes to execute tasks

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i have a cloud function watching document creation and it is working fine, but it just needs minutes to execute the tasks.

Here is the code

```ts
export const incrementUserCategoryCounter = functions.firestore
  .document("imgs/{imgDocId}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const imgData = snapshot.data();
    const catId = imgData.catId;
    const uid = imgData.cid;
    const userCatDocRef = db.collection(`users/${uid}/categories/`).doc(catId);
    const catDocRef = db.collection("categories").doc(catId);
    userCatDocRef
      .get()
      .then((doc: any) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          userCatDocRef
            .update({...})
            .then(() => {
              console.log("Transaction success! Increment for id", catId);
            })
            .catch((err: string) => {
              console.log("Transaction failure:", err);
            });
        } else {
          userCatDocRef.create({...});
          catDocRef.update({...});
          console.log(
            "No doc for this category, doc now created with counter 1."
          );
        }
      })
      .catch((err: string) => {
        console.log("Transaction failure:", err);
      });
  });
```

And here the log of this function:

```js
2023-11-13T07:28:11 No doc for this category, doc now created with counter 1.
2023-11-13T07:24:56 Function execution took 162 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
2023-11-13T07:24:56 Function execution started
```

It needs 3 minutes to execute just these little updates/adds.

What have i done wrong?

//EDIT
With this modified code it now needs 1600ms :D

```js
export const incrementUserCategoryCounter = functions.firestore
  .document('imgs/{imgDocId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const imgData = snapshot.data();
    const catId = imgData.catId;
    const uid = imgData.cid;
    const userCatDocRef = db.collection(`users/${uid}/categories/`).doc(catId);
    // const catDocRef = db.collection('categories').doc(catId);
    try {
      const userCatDoc = await userCatDocRef.get();
      if (userCatDoc.exists) {
        const doc = userCatDoc.data()!;
        let newLast10 = {...};
        ...
        await incUserCat(uid, catId, newLast10, 1);
      } else {
        await userCatDocRef.create({...});
        console.log('No doc, adding it.');
      }
      await incCat(catId, 1);
      return null;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
      return null;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test your Cloud Function but the behaviour you describe is fairly typical of a wrong management of the Cloud Function life cycle: In background Cloud Functions calling asynchronous methods you must return a Promise to tell to the CF platform to wait until the promise is fulfilled or rejected before cleaning up the function. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more detail.

In your case you don't return the global [Promises chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining) and in the else block you even don't chain the two asynchronous method calls.

The following code should do the trick. Since you use `async` for the callback function I've adapted your code with `await` instead of using [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). This also allow to simplify the code in the `if`/`else` block in terms of Promise chaining.

```js
export const incrementUserCategoryCounter = functions.firestore
  .document("imgs/{imgDocId}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

    try {
      const imgData = snapshot.data();
      const catId = imgData.catId;
      const uid = imgData.cid;
      const userCatDocRef = db.collection(`users/${uid}/categories/`).doc(catId);
      const catDocRef = db.collection("categories").doc(catId);

      const doc = await userCatDocRef;
      if (doc.exists) {
        await userCatDocRef.update({ ...});
        console.log("Transaction success! Increment for id", catId);
      } else {
        await userCatDocRef.create({ ...});
        await catDocRef.update({ ...}); // Note that you could use a batched write
        console.log(
          "No doc for this category, doc now created with counter 1."
        );
      }
      return null;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return null;
    }

  });
```

Comment: Hey @Bourbon, did you have the time to test the proposed solution?